# Why would I put code in __init__.py files?

Tags: python, module

I am looking for what type of code would I put in `__init__.py` files and what are the best practices related to this. Or, is it a bad practice in general ?

Any reference to known documents that explain this is also very much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is __init__.py for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Answer (score 71):

Libraries and frameworks usually use initialization code in `__init__.py` files **to neatly hide internal structure and provide a uniform interface to the user**.

Let's take the example of [Django forms module](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/forms). Various functions and classes in forms module are defined in different files based on their classification.

```
forms/
  __init__.py
  extras/
    ...
  fields.py
  forms.py
  widgets.py
  ...
```

Now if you were to create a form, you would have to know in which file each function is defined and your code to create a contact form will have to look something like this (which is incovenient and ugly).

```
 class CommentForm(forms.forms.Form):
    name = forms.fields.CharField() 
    url = forms.fields.URLField()
    comment = forms.fields.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.Textarea)
```

Instead, in Django you can just refer to various widgets, forms, fields etc. directly from the forms namespace.

```
from django import forms

class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    url = forms.URLField()
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

How is this possible? To make this possible, Django adds the following statement to `forms/__init__.py` file which import all the widgets, forms, fields etc. into the `forms` namespace.

```
from widgets import *
from fields import *
from forms import *
from models import *
```

As you can see, this simplifies your life when creating the forms because now you don't have to worry about in where each function/class is defined and just use all of these directly from `forms` namespace. This is just one example but you can see examples like these in other frameworks and libraries.

Comment: That's a fairly good answer, but in the example of e.g beautifulsoup4, which seem to gather a lot of the main functionality in the __init__.py-file?
Why would they do this?
https://github.com/getanewsletter/BeautifulSoup4/blob/master/bs4/__init__.py

Answer (score 14):

One of the best practices in that area is to import all needed classes from your library (look at [mongoengine](https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/__init__.py), for example). So, a user of your library can do this:

```
from coollibrary import OneClass, SecondClass
```

instead of

```
from coollibrary.package import OneClass
from coollibrary.anotherpackage import SecondClass
```

Also, good practice is include in `__init__.py` version constant

Comment: What do you mean by version constant ? Could you please clear this statement out ?

Answer (score 7):

1. For convenience: The other users will not need to know your functions' exactly location.

   ```
   your_package/
     __init__.py
     file1.py/
     file2.py/
       ...
     fileN.py

   # in __init__.py
   from file1 import *
   from file2 import *
   ...
   from fileN import *

   # in file1.py
   def add():
       pass
   ```

   then others can call add() by

   ```
   from your_package import add
   ```

   without knowing file1, like

   ```
   from your_package.file1 import add
   ```
2. Put something for initializing. For example, the logging(this should put in the top level):

   ```
   import logging.config
   logging.config.dictConfig(Your_logging_config)
   ```