# Pythonic way to write package for easy importing

Tags: package, python, python-module

I have a very simple package, which I eventually want to release through PyPI, which has a directory tree like the following:

```
daterangeparser/
   __init__.py
   parse_date_range.py
   test.py
```

`parse_date_range.py` defines a function called `parse`.

What is the easiest and most pythonic way for me to set up the package for easy importing of the `parse` function, and how can I do it?

At the moment I have to do `from daterangeparser.parse_date_range import parse` which seems rather clunky. I'd rather do `from daterangeparser import parse`, which seems simpler and more pythonic, but I can't seem to work out how to get this to work (do I need to put something else in `__init__.py`? Or, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need `parse_date_range` module? The package name `daterangeparser` already conveys the intent, `daterangeparser.parse_date_range` doesn't make any sense.

You can move all the code from `parse_date_range` module to `__init__` and then you can import `parse` like `from daterangeparser import parse`.

Comment: Is this good Python programming practice? I thought that `__init__.py` was meant to be kept for admin-type things?

Comment: Take a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831148/why-would-i-put-python-code-in-init-py-files. In your case, I think it is OK to have content of ``parse_date_range`` in ``__init__``.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add:

```
from .parse_date_range import parse
```

Into `__init__.py` to allow this usage. That's the best way.

You could also use an absolute import if you wanted:

```
from daterangeparser.parse_date_range import parse
```

Either of these options puts the `parse()` function into the `daterangeparser` namespace, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in `__init__.py`:

```
from daterangeparser.parse_date_range import parse
```

Then you can import it the way you want.