# How do I avoid users of my code having to type redundant import lines?

Tags: python, import, coding-style

So I have a project called "Pants" that lives on GitHub.com.  Originally the project was a single `.py` file called `pants.py`.

```
Pants/
    pants.py
    README.md
```

and users could import and use it as follows:

```
import pants
w = pants.World()
```

---

Both of these feel fine to me.  Then I read up on how to structure a project with unit tests included, and initially reorganized my project thusly:

```
Pants/
    pants.py
    README.md
    test/
        __init__.py
        test_world.py
        test_ant.py
```

The problem with this is that although users can still import the same logical way, there is no `pants.test` module/package!  No problem, I thought, I'll simply add another `__init__.py` file:

```
Pants/
    __init__.py
    pants.py
    README.md
    test/
        __init__.py
        test_world.py
        test_ant.py
```

But now the imports feel incredibly repetitive:

```
import Pants.pants
w = Pants.pants.World()
```

---

It just feels like there is a better way!  Right now, my project is structured like this:

```
Pants/
    README.md
    pants/
        __init__.py
        ants.py
        world.py
        solver.py
        test/
            __init__.py
            test_world.py
            test_ant.py
```

However, the import lines users are faced with are equally repetitive:

```
import pants.world
import pants.solver
w = pants.world.World()
s = pants.solver.Solver()
```

---

Now I know you can alias these things to shorter equivalents, such as `import pants.world.World as World` but the import line itself still feels repetitive.  Any suggestions on how to avoid such repetition while retaining proper project structure?  Does any of this have to change if I were to, say, put it up for installation via `pip`?

Comment: take a look at [`asyncio/__init__.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ae405c11193b/Lib/asyncio/__init__.py). If `world.py` and `solver.py` are implementation details; your users may use the flat namespace i.e., the only import is `import pants`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I thought I had read somewhere that putting code into `__init__.py` was a bad practice, but after looking at how asyncio does it, along with [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831148/why-would-i-put-python-code-in-init-py-files), I know exactly how to proceed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it, I kept my package structure the same, and added the following lines to `pants/__init__.py`:

```
from .ant import Ant
from .world import World
from .solver import Solver
```

Then I was able to change the import lines at the top of my demo file to:

```
from pants import World
from pants import Solver
```

Comment: Since I don't have the reputation for upvoting an answer to my question, and also since the help I received was technically found in links, I thought I would answer my own question explicitly. That way the next person to have the question can directly see how the changes I made to solve my problem without relying on the existence of link content.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a separate `pants.py` put that code inside of `__init__.py`. Then when someone does `import pants` it loads that `__init__.py`. (I'd avoid using the uppercase "Pants" as uppercase is generally for classnames)

If your users need `world` or `solver` separately you can also do

```
from pants import world,solver
w = world.World()
s = solver.Solver()
```

If they wanted everything from your package they could do

```
from pants import *
```

Comment: don't use wildcard imports outside of `__init__.py` or Python REPL

Comment: Yes best practice is to not import everything.