# Can I write a method/function in a __init__.py file?

Tags: python

Can I write a method/function in a `__init__.py` file? as demonstrated below

Example:

In `__init__.py` file

```
import subprocess
import config


def ssh_exe(cmd):
    try:
        ssh_cmd = "ssh root@{0} {1}".format(config.ip, cmd)
        out = subprocess.check_output(ssh_cmd)
        return out
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Related, probably dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Comment: @Prune Yes, I tried and it works fine without error. But how to access the method/function in another function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure, they are normal files. Only difference is that they define that the folder is a package.

From [python official basic tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` **can just be an empty file**, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.

Note that you usually don't put your code in `__init__.py` but instead define it in the packages' modules and import only the names you want to expose in the package namespace.

Here's an example on how to access then, suppose you have this directory structure:

```
Development/
   main.py
   setup.py
   myprogram/
       __init__.py
       other.py
```

The `myprogram` folder is considered a package because of `__init__.py` so in `main.py` you can do:

```
import myprogram
myprogram.something() # defined in `__init__.py`
import myprogram.other # the submodule other.py inside the package
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how to access the method/function in another python file?

Comment: Thanks @nosklo. I got it.

Comment: It's not the only difference. `__init__.py` is automatically executed in certain circumstances. There's a fair bit to read on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831148/why-would-i-put-code-in-init-py-files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70159126/is-it-bad-practise-to-not-use-init-py-files-in-a-python-project https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for