# Is it bad practise to not use __init__.py files in a python project?

Tags: python

I am working on a python project that doesn't have too much cross use of functions in different files. I also don't have cases where a file is needing to use something in a different folder than the one it is in.

Is it bad practise for me not to have any `__init__.py` files in the project at the moment. I don't fully understand the benefit of adding them in?

Comment: If you need them, you _need_ them -- you can't `import` your code without them. If everything works as-is without them, then you don't need them. It's not a "is this good practice?" thing, it's a "what do you need to do to to make your code work at all?" thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `__init__.py` file makes Python treat a folder as a module, so you can `import foldername`. It is commonly used for large modules.

If you're not doing that, you don't need an `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:
"The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages. This prevents directories with a common name, such as string , unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path."

So you need it to import scripts.